Blender startup script runs too early compared to keymap async
def Keymap_Register():
    window_manager = bpy.context.window_manager

    for i in window_manager.keyconfigs.active.keymaps:
        print(i)

# add global keys
    global_keys(add_json_context)

gives me something along the lines of:
################# and all the maps before
<bpy_struct, KeyMap("Font") at 0x000002737CD16288>
<bpy_struct, KeyMap("Object Non-modal") at 0x000002737CD19768>
<bpy_struct, KeyMap("3D View") at 0x000002737CD176C8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Blender\stable\blender-4.2.3-lts+stable.0e22e4fcea03\4.2\scripts\modules\bpy\utils\__init__.py", line 238, in register_module_call
    register()
  File "C:\Blender\stable\blender-4.2.3-lts+stable.0e22e4fcea03\4.2\scripts\startup\HEAVYPOLY_HOTKEYS.py", line 199, in register
    Keymap_Register()
  File "C:\Blender\stable\blender-4.2.3-lts+stable.0e22e4fcea03\4.2\scripts\startup\HEAVYPOLY_HOTKEYS.py", line 188, in Keymap_Register
    global_keys(add_json_context)
  File "C:\Blender\stable\blender-4.2.3-lts+stable.0e22e4fcea03\4.2\scripts\startup\HEAVYPOLY_HOTKEYS.py", line 163, in global_keys
    add_keymap_attrs(
  File "C:\Blender\stable\blender-4.2.3-lts+stable.0e22e4fcea03\4.2\scripts\startup\HEAVYPOLY_HOTKEYS.py", line 50, in add_keymap_attrs
    keymap_items_context = get_keymap_items_ctx(keymap_config, keymap_context)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Blender\stable\blender-4.2.3-lts+stable.0e22e4fcea03\4.2\scripts\startup\HEAVYPOLY_HOTKEYS.py", line 20, in get_keymap_items_ctx
    return window_manager.keyconfigs[keymap_config].keymaps[keymap_context].keymap_items
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Graph Editor" not found'
<bpy_struct, KeyMap("Window") at 0x000002737CD141E8>
<bpy_struct, KeyMap("Screen") at 0x000002737CD149C8>
################# and all the other maps after (including Graph Editor)

which means that the keymaps are loaded async and that loading keymaps in startup does not seem to work as often as effectively as it misses the keymap configs that are not loaded yet.
What would be a solution to solve an issue like this? I tried:

def delayed_keymap_registration():
    Keymap_Register()
    return None  # Stops the timer

bpy.app.timers.register(delayed_keymap_registration, first_interval=2.0)


def register():
    Keymap_Register()

def unregister():
    Keymap_Register()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()


```

